# making a WCS Munsell color chart in R, problems with order in scale_fill_manual, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to make a Munsell for color chart for the chips used by the World Color Survey. It should look like this:

[image]

The information needed can be found on the WCS page, [here](https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/wcs/data.html#wmt), I take the following steps:

```
library(munsell) # https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/munsell/munsell.pdf
library(ggplot2)

# take the "cnum-vhcm-lab-new.txt" file from: https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/wcs/data.html#wmt
# change by replacing .50 with .5 removing .00 after hue values

WCS <- read.csv("cnum-vhcm-lab-new.txt", sep = "\t", header = T)
WCS$hex <- mnsl2hex(hvc2mnsl(hue = WCS$MunH, value = ceiling(WCS$MunV), chroma = WCS$C), fix = T)

# this works, but the order of tiles is messed up
ggplot(aes(x=H, y=V, fill=hex), data = WCS) +   
  geom_tile(aes(x=H, y=V), show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = WCS$hex) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 40))
```

The result:

[image]

Clearly, the chips are not ordered along hue and value but with reference to some other dimension, perhaps even order in the original data frame. I also have to revert the order on the y-axis. I guess the solution will have to do with `factor()` and `reorder()`, but how to do it?

Comment: Can you provide the code for "change by removing .5 and .00 after hue values"?  I keep getting errors.

Comment: Hi Brian, just in text edit or the like, before reading in the file in R. Find & replace, actually I didn't put this correctly, it should be .50 > .5 and .00 > remove altogether. I'll edit my OP now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP.  TL;DR - you should be using `scale_fill_identity()` rather than `scale_fill_manual()`.

Now for the long description: At its core, `ggplot2` functions on *mapping* the columns of your data to specific features on the plot, which `ggplot2` refers to as "aesthetics" using the `aes()` function.  Positioning is defined by mapping certain columns of your data to `x` and `y` aesthetics, and the different colors in your tiles are mapped to `fill` using `aes()` as well.

The mapping for `fill` does not specify *color*, but only specifies which things should be *different colors*.  When mapped this way, it means that rows in your data (observations) that have the same value in column mapped to the `fill` aesthetic will be the same color, and observations that have different values in the column mapped to the `fill` aesthetic will be different colors.  Importantly, **this does not specify the color, but only specifies if colors should be different!**

The default behavior is that `ggplot2` will determine the colors to use by applying a default scale.  For continuous (numeric) values, a continuous scale is applied, and for discrete values (like a vector of characters), a discrete scale is applied.

To see the default behavior, just remove `scale_fill_manual(...)` from your plot code.  I've recopied your code below and added the needed revisions to programmatically remove and adjust the `".50"` and `".00"` changes to `WCS$MunH`.  The code below should work entirely if you have downloaded the original .txt file from the link you provided.

```
library(munsell)
library(ggplot2)

WCS <- read.csv("cnum-vhcm-lab-new.txt", sep = "\t", header = T)
WCS$MunH <- gsub('.50','.5', WCS$MunH)  # remove trailing "0" after ".50"
WCS$MunH <- gsub('.00',  '', WCS$MunH)  # remove ".00" altogether

WCS$V <- factor(WCS$V)  # needed to flip the axis

WCS$hex <- mnsl2hex(hvc2mnsl(hue = WCS$MunH, value = ceiling(WCS$MunV), chroma = WCS$C), fix = T)

ggplot(aes(x=H, y=V, fill=hex), data = WCS) +   
  geom_tile(aes(x=H, y=V), show.legend = F, width=0.8, height=0.8) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(WCS$V))) +  # flipping the axis
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 40)) +
  coord_fixed() + # force all tiles to be "square"
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

You have `show.legend = F` in there, but there should be 324 different values mapped to the `WCS$hex` column (i.e. `length(unique(WCS$hex))`).

When using `scale_fill_manual(values=...)`, you are supplying the names of the colors to be used, but they are not mapped to the same positions in your column `WCS$hex`.  They are applied according to the way in which `ggplot2` decides to organize the levels of `WCS$hex` as if it were a factor.

In order to tell `ggplot2` to basically ignore the mapping and just *color according to the actual color name you see in the column mapped to `fill`*, you use `scale_fill_identity()`.  This will necessarily remove the ability to show any legend, since it kind of removes the mapping and recoloring that is the default behavior of `aes(fill=...)`.  Regardless, this should solve your issue:

```
ggplot(aes(x=H, y=V, fill=hex), data = WCS) +   
  geom_tile(aes(x=H, y=V), width=0.8, height=0.8) +
  scale_fill_identity() +   # assign color based on text
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(WCS$V))) +  # flipping the axis
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 40)) +
  coord_fixed() + # force all tiles to be "square"
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The main thing is to use the right color scale (`scale_fill_identity`). This ensures the hex values are uses as the color for the tiles.

```r
library(munsell) # https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/munsell/munsell.pdf
library(ggplot2)

WCS <- read.csv(url('https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/wcs/data/cnum-maps/cnum-vhcm-lab-new.txt'), sep = "\t", header = T)
WCS$hex <- mnsl2hex(hvc2mnsl(hue = gsub('.00','',gsub('.50', '.5',WCS$MunH)), value = ceiling(WCS$MunV), chroma = WCS$C), fix = T)

# this works, but the order of tiles is messed up
ggplot(aes(x=H, y=V, fill=hex), data = WCS) +   
  geom_tile(aes(x=H, y=V), show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 40))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>